# How can I improve the look of my table? (no white space, nice font size, and not going off the end of page)

Tags: tables, spacing, columns, width

I just want a nice plot but I try different things and sometimes it goes of the page, or there is white space (like now). I would like adequate spacing between lines and varying font heights.

Here is my code:

```
    %\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{longtabu}{|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}|}
     & \bfseries{AVISO} & \bfseries{CU} & \bfseries{GSFC} & \bfseries{NOAA} & \bfseries{CSIRO}  \\
    \midrule
    \bfseries{Minimum Ocean depth} & 0\,m & 120\,m & 120\,m & 0\,m & 0\,m \\
    \bfseries{SSHA outlier removal} & - & 2\,m & - & 1\,m & - \\
    \bfseries{Along track / box-gridded} & box-gridded & Along track & Along track & box-gridded & box-gridded \\
    \bfseries{Box resolution} & $3^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ & - & - & $3^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ & $1^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ \\
    \bfseries{Time range of average} & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & monthly \\
    \bfseries{Weighting} & area weighted, inclination weighted & inclination weighted & inclination weighted & area weighted & area weighted \\ 
    \bottomrule 
    \end{longtabu} 
    \caption{caption here}
\end{table}
```

I also tried using `\usepackage{tabularx}` with no luck, I guess I am missing something but I'm not sure what....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>***These are the fallible opinions of one small person.***</sup>

This is going outside of the scope of TeX, but there are a few things to stick to when designing tables.  I am by no means a typographer or graphic designer, but these are some things I have picked up along my travels:

- **Keep your headers short!**

  Nobody really needs detailed column headers.
  If the headers can't be short and sweet and still be understood,
   then you haven't explained the table well enough in the text.
- ***Never* use vertical rules.**

  Read the documentation of the `booktabs` package!
  (I imagine this may very well have been
   written/influenced by a true typographer.)
  While there may be *very special* cases where such rules are appropriate,
   this is not one of those cases.
- **Don't be too verbose.**

  Leave some inference to the reader in the interest of
   keeping the information transparent.
  Don't obfuscate the information, but don't clutter it, either.
- **Left-align text; right-align numbers.**
- **Keep similar content in columns.**
- **Put units in column headers, not in the body.**
- **(TeX-specific) Use macros and column types appropriately.**

  Instead of bolding each header individually,
   declare the appropriate behavior as part of the column type.
  Instead of using the same structure over and over again by hand,
   declare a macro and implement
   the more verbose but typographically correct setting.

#### Possible improvement

[image: comparison]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}     % not needed with new table

\begin{document}    %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%%%%%     %%%%%
\centering%%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     OLD TABLE     %%%%%
%%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%%%%%     %%%%%
\begin{longtabu}{|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}| p{0.1\textwidth}|}
  & \bfseries{AVISO} & \bfseries{CU} & \bfseries{GSFC} & \bfseries{NOAA} & \bfseries{CSIRO}  \\
  \midrule
  \bfseries{Minimum Ocean depth} & 0\,m & 120\,m & 120\,m & 0\,m & 0\,m \\
  \bfseries{SSHA outlier removal} & - & 2\,m & - & 1\,m & - \\
  \bfseries{Along track / box-gridded} & box-gridded & Along track & Along track & box-gridded & box-gridded \\
  \bfseries{Box resolution} & $3^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ & - & - & $3^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ & $1^{\circ}$x$1^{\circ}$ \\
  \bfseries{Time range of average} & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & monthly \\
  \bfseries{Weighting} & area weighted, inclination weighted & inclination weighted & inclination weighted & area weighted & area weighted \\ 
  \bottomrule 
\end{longtabu} 
%%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%%%%%     %%%%%
%%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     NEW TABLE     %%%%%
%%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%     %%%%%%%%%     %%%%%
\newcommand\Dimen[2]{$#1^\circ\times#^d\circ$} % box dimensions
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\bfseries}r} % 'Header' column type.
% Technically speaking, you should avoid bolding things in tables.  If
% you must though, this is the way to do it.

\begin{tabular}{Hrrlrll}
  \toprule
  System & Depth (m) & Outliers & Orientation & Resolution   & Avg. Time & Weighting              \\
  \midrule
  \addlinespace[1ex]
  CU     & 120       & 2        & track       &              & cycle     & inclination            \\
  GSFC   & 120       &          & track       &              & cycle     & inclination            \\[1ex]
  AVISO  & 0         &          & box         & \Dimen{3}{2} & cycle     & area\slash inclination \\
  NOAA   & 0         & 1        & box         & \Dimen{3}{1} & cycle     & area                   \\
  CSIRO  & 0         &          & box         & \Dimen{1}{1} & month     & area                   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Obligatory

[image: data tables! remove to improve...]

Comment: Awesome animation!! I can think of only one improvement in the table and that is to center the "depth" and "outliers" data in the column, but still have the numbers right aligned.  Similarly, the data for columns "Orientation" and "Avg. Time" should be centered and still be left aligned. Oh, and the "Weighting" title should be centered.  Anyway, that's just my opinion...

Comment: @PeterGrill A lot of this stuff *is* just opinion, but that doesn't make it wrong. (In fact, there are very few things that are 1) easy to do in LaTeX and 2) very, very wrong. I've never *seen* anything but headers aligned with content (and it seems to be advised against in the animation), but I imagine there are appropriate times to do so.  Is there an easy way that you know of to have `array` like column-insertion syntax for rows?  Something that crosses `&`-boundaries, but stops at ``\\``?

Comment: Agreed. I guess I will have to look more carefully at my tables.  Not sure I understand your question. But, if it is about my comment about "centering in a column but still be left aligned", I don't know of any easy way. Do recall seeing an answer here about using additional columns for the header (for the case where the title of a column is wider than the content).

Answer (score 2):

I would also get rid of all vertical lines, and I wouldn't use *bold* for the entries of the header row. I suggest using the `tabularx` package to ease the job of getting the five data columns all have the same width. In the "Box resolution row, I suggest using `\times` instead of the text-mode `x`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins as needed
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{1.5in}*{5}{L}@{}}
& AVISO & CU & GSFC & NOAA & CSIRO  \\
\midrule
Minimum Ocean depth & 0\,m & 120\,m & 120\,m & 0\,m & 0\,m \\[1ex]
SSHA outlier removal & -- & 2\,m & -- & 1\,m & -- \\[1ex]
Along track\slash box-gridded & box-gridded & Along track & Along track & box-gridded & box-gridded \\[1ex]
Box resolution & $3^{\circ}{\times}1^{\circ}$ & - & - & $3^{\circ}{\times}1^{\circ}$ & $1^{\circ}{\times}1^{\circ}$ \\[1ex]
Time range of average & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & per cycle & monthly \\[1ex]
Weighting & area weighted, inclination weighted & inclination weighted & inclination weighted & area weighted & area weighted \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 
\caption{caption here}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use the given table designs, it looks a lot nicer!